# How to add custom button to Lightning layout

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have custom button that runs some javascript code, I added it to page layout in Salesforce classic. But when I switch to lightning, on record page my button is missing. I tried creating custom lightning page, but I can only add lightning components to it. How can I add a button to standard lightning layout?

I have built a button that redirects to another web application using some values from current record and I need this button to be on record page layout, but in lightning too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. Javascript buttons aren't supported by Lightning. Lightning pages are single page applications. Most everything in Lightning is done using Actions.

See [Page Layouts in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=layouts_in_lex.htm&language=en_US) from Salesforce Help where it explicitly says:

> Custom buttons that call JavaScript aren’t supported in Lightning Experience.

**UPDATE** - Use the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter recreates your org’s JavaScript buttons as Lightning components, quick actions, or other solutions — all without touching your original buttons.

See [Salesforce blog about this.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/convert-javascript-buttons-to-lightning-friendly-alternatives-with-the-lightning-experience-configuration-converter.html)

Comment: Can you add some documentation to back this up? You're in the `Low Quality Posts` queue for this one.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Will do, let me go find a link.

Comment: @crmprogdev So the only option for me to run my js is to create custom lightning component that I will add to lightning page?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not certain that you'll be able to do it with a Lightning Component as I've not attempted anything like that myself and I believe there are some limitations on what part of the window a component has access to, but it would seem that would be the most likely approach to take if you need to try and pre-populate values from a current record.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_in_lex.htm&language=en_US&type=0#sfx_no_support_for_js_buttons <--- The red warning under `Standard and Custom Buttons`

Comment: Now you can use converter for existing buttons.  
https://lightning-configuration.salesforce.com/